# Parallelizing for the Fortran Nested loop

Tags: fortran, openmp, nested-loops

I used OpenMP with COLLAPSE clause to parallelise the nested the Fortran loop. The code can be compiled successfully but it gives me the following error message when I run it.

```
Loading compiler-rt version 2022.0.2
Loading oclfpga version 2022.0.2
  Load "debugger" to debug DPC++ applications with the gdb-oneapi debugger.
  Load "dpl" for additional DPC++ APIs: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDPL
Loading mkl version 2022.0.2
Loading mpi version 2021.5.1

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   RANK 0 PID 15005 RUNNING AT login
=   KILLED BY SIGNAL: 11 (Segmentation fault)
===================================================================================

[1]+  Done                    ./run.sh
```

Here is the nested part in my code

```
PROGRAM CODE
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER                         ::             ra(2)                         
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             ch(3)                         
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             it                            
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             mi                            
INTEGER                         ::             nm                            
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             te                            
INTEGER                         ::             km(3)                         
INTEGER                         ::             ps(3)                         
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lr(3,3)                       
INTEGER                         ::             na                            
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             ap(:,:)                       
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             ns(:,:)                       
INTEGER                         ::             po(3)                         
INTEGER                         ::             nb                            
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             tv(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ok(:,:,:)                     
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             oo(:,:,:)                     
INTEGER                         ::             lwork, info
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             ipiv(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             work(:)
INTEGER                         ::             i, j, k, l, m                 
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             kp(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ks(:,:,:)                     
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ol(:,:,:)                     
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             ei(:)                         
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             th(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ll(:,:,:)                     
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             sr(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rl(:,:,:)                     
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ls(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rs(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rg(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ag(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             tr(:,:)                       
COMPLEX (KIND=dp)               ::             ic                            
COMPLEX (KIND=dp)               ::             pf                            
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             fd(3)                         
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t1(:,:,:,:)                   
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t2(:)                         
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t3(:)                         
INTEGER                         ::             omp_get_num_threads           
INTEGER                         ::             omp_get_thread_num            
INTEGER                         ::             num_thread                    
INTEGER                         ::             id_thread                     
k = ra(2) - ra(1)
ALLOCATE (ll(5,k,k))
ALLOCATE (sr(k,k))
ALLOCATE (rl(5,k,k))
ALLOCATE (ls(k,k))
ALLOCATE (rs(k,k))
ALLOCATE (rg(k,k))
ALLOCATE (ag(k,k))
ALLOCATE (tr(k,k))
ALLOCATE (ipiv(k))
ALLOCATE (work(2*k-1))
ALLOCATE (th(nb,nb))
lwork = 2*k-1
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(num_thread)
num_thread = omp_get_num_threads()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
ALLOCATE (t1(nm,km(1)*km(2)*km(3),k,k))
t1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
ALLOCATE (t2(nm))
t2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
ALLOCATE (t3(nm))
t3 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)

!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j,l,m,pf,th,ll,sr,rl,ls,rs,rg,ag,ipiv,work,lwork,info,fd,tr)&
!$OMP             SHARED(po,km,kp,nm,nb,ei,ic,tv,lr,ol,ks,ra,k,ch,te) COLLAPSE(2)&
!$OMP             REDUCTION(+:t1,t2,t3)
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   DO j = 1, km(1)*km(2)*km(3), 1
      DO l = 1, nb, 1
         DO m = 1, po(1)*po(2)*po(3), 1
            pf = EXP(ic*(kp(j,1)*(tv(1,m)*lr(1,1)+tv(2,m)*lr(2,1)+tv(3,m)*lr(3,1))+kp(j,2)*(tv(1,m)*lr(1,2)+tv(2,m)*lr(2,2)+tv(3,m)*lr(3,2))+kp(j,3)*(tv(1,m)*lr(1,3)+tv(2,m)*lr(2,3)+tv(3,m)*lr(3,3))))
            th(:,l) = pf*((ei(i)+ic)*ol(:,l,m)-ks(:,l,m))
         END DO
      END DO
      ll(1,:,:) = th(ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k,ra(1)-k*2:ra(2)-k*2)
      ll(2,:,:) = th(ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k,ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k)    
      ll(3,:,:) = th(ra(1)-k*2:ra(2)-k*2,ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k)
      ll(4,:,:) = th(ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k,ra(1):ra(2))        
      ll(5,:,:) = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k)        
      sr = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1):ra(2))                   
      rl(1,:,:) = th(ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k,ra(1)+k*2:ra(2)+k*2)
      rl(2,:,:) = th(ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k,ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k)    
      rl(3,:,:) = th(ra(1)+k*2:ra(2)+k*2,ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k)
      rl(4,:,:) = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k)        
      rl(5,:,:) = th(ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k,ra(1):ra(2))        
      ls = MATMUL(MATMUL(ll(1,:,:),ll(2,:,:)),ll(3,:,:)) 
      ll(2,:,:) = ll(2,:,:) - ls                         
      rs = MATMUL(MATMUL(rl(1,:,:),rl(2,:,:)),rl(3,:,:)) 
      rl(2,:,:) = rl(2,:,:) - rs                         
      rg = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
      rg = sr-ls-rs
      CALL ZGETRF(ra(2)-ra(1),ra(2)-ra(1),rg,l,ipiv,info)
      CALL ZGETRI(ra(2)-ra(1),rg,ra(2)-ra(1),ipiv,work,lwork,info)
      DO l = 1, k, 1
         ag(l,:) = DCONJG(rg(:,l))
      END DO
      fd(1) = 1.0d0/(EXP((ei(i)-ch(1))/te)+1.0d0)
      fd(2) = 1.0d0/(EXP((ei(i)-ch(3))/te)+1.0d0)
      IF (fd(1) > fd(2)) THEN
         fd(3) = fd(1)
         fd(1) = fd(2)
         fd(2) = fd(3)
         fd(3) = fd(2)-fd(1)
      ELSE IF (fd(1) == fd(2)) THEN
              fd(3) = 1.0d0
      ELSE
         fd(3) = fd(2)-fd(1)
      END IF
      t1(i,j,:,:) = t1(i,j,:,:)+fd(3)*MATMUL(MATMUL(rg,ls+rs),ag)/2.0d0-fd(1)*IMAG(rg)
      tr = MATMUL(MATMUL(MATMUL(ls,ag),rs),rg)
      DO l = 1, k, 1
         t2(i) = t2(i)+tr(l,l)
      END DO
      t2(i) = t2(i)*fd(3)
      tr = rg - ag
      DO l = 1, k, 1
         t3(i) = t3(i)+tr(l,l)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

100 STOP
END PROGRAM CODE
```

I am not sure whether this problem comes from the limited memory on my computer because it still persists after I reduce the computational loading (smaller values for 'nm' and 'km' variables in the nested Fortran loop). Would anyone please give me some suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

I add a small complete example, which has the same structure in the code above, and put it below. Would anyone please have a look at it and give me some suggestions; particularly, the COLLAPSE and REDUCTION clause in the OpenMP for the nested loop? Do you think it is correctly written? Thank you.

```
PROGRAM TES
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER                         ::             i, j, k, l, m
INTEGER                         ::             na = 177
INTEGER                         ::             nm = 100
INTEGER                         ::             km(3)
INTEGER                         ::             po(3)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             kp(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             th(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp)               ::             ic = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 1.0d0)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t1(:,:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t2(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t3(:)
INTEGER                         ::             omp_get_num_threads
INTEGER                         ::             omp_get_thread_num
INTEGER                         ::             num_thread
INTEGER                         ::             id_thread

km(1) = 100
km(2) = 1
km(3) = 75
ALLOCATE (kp(km(1)*km(2)*km(3),3))
DO i = 1, km(1), 1
   DO j = 1, km(2), 1
      DO k = 1, km(3), 1
         kp((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k,1) = DBLE(i)
         kp((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k,2) = DBLE(j)
         kp((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k,3) = DBLE(k)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
po(1) = 1
po(2) = 0
po(3) = 5
ALLOCATE (th(na,na))
ALLOCATE (t1(nm,km(1)*km(2)*km(3),na,na))
ALLOCATE (t2(nm))
ALLOCATE (t3(nm))
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(num_thread)
num_thread = omp_get_num_threads()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j,k,l,m,th)&
!$OMP             SHARED(km,kp,nm,po,ic) COLLAPSE(2)&
!$OMP             REDUCTION(+:t1,t2,t3)
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   DO j = 1, km(1)*km(2)*km(3), 1
      th = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
      DO k = 1, na, 1
         DO l = 1, na, 1
            DO m = 1, (po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1), 1
               th(l,k) = th(l,k) + kp(j,1)*k + kp(j,2)*ic - kp(j,3)*l
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
      t1(i,j,:,:) = th*(i-j+ic)
      DO k = 1, na, 1
         t2(i) = t2(i) + th(k,k)*(i*ic-j)
      END DO
      DO k = na, 1, -1
         t3(i) = t3(i) + th(k,na-k+1)*(i*ic+j)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='output.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   DO j = 1, km(1)*km(2)*km(3), 1
      DO k = 1, na, 1
         WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) t1(i,j,k,:)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) t2(i)
END DO
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) t3(i)
END DO
CLOSE (UNIT=3)

DEALLOCATE (kp)
DEALLOCATE (th)
DEALLOCATE (t1)
DEALLOCATE (t2)
DEALLOCATE (t3)

STOP
END PROGRAM TES
```

Comment: For segfaults, debug your program for error checking. Like `ifort -g -traceback -check`. The code is way too long to just look for an error without any line number information. Also, use some empty lines to make the code syricture better readable. And use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: First of all: did you check that the serial version of the code (i.e. compiled without OpenMP, or run with a single thread) run correctly?

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the suggestion. I modified my post and only paste the nested loop part here. I can successfully compile the code but encounters the error above when I run it.

Comment: @PierU When I try to run it in the serial way, I do not encounter any error. Would you please have a look at the modified code and give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Your current code does not allocate `th` at all. Maybe there is more, but I stopped looking. If you make a smaller [mcve], make sure that it actually keeps the same error and that it works in serial. Don't forget those debugging flags. Also, remove the unnecessary reference to MPI.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the suggestions. I forgot to add the allocation for 'th' variable in my code. I have modified it. I also added -g -traceback -check into my compiling file and the compilation could be done successfully but the same error still persisted when I ran the code. I wonder there may be something wrong with my compiling or job script files. I paste them below. Would you please have a look at them and give me some more suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @Valdimir This is my compiling file. `#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=cpu
#SBATCH --job-name=qt
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
module load compiler/2022.0.2
module load mkl/2022.0.2
module load mpi/2021.5.1
mpiifort -qmkl -qopenmp -fp-model strict -no-wrap-margin -g -traceback -check CODE.f90 -o CODE`

Comment: Just compile the test code simply in one `ifort` command. There is no need whatsoever for build scripts for this simple test case. And remove the unnecessary `use MPI`.

Comment: @Valdimir This is the message after I compiled my code and it seems that it could be compiled successfully. `Loading compiler version 2022.0.2
Loading tbb version 2021.5.1
Loading compiler-rt version 2022.0.2
Loading oclfpga version 2022.0.2
  Load "debugger" to debug DPC++ applications with the gdb-oneapi debugger.
  Load "dpl" for additional DPC++ APIs: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDPL
Loading mkl version 2022.0.2
Loading mpi version 2021.5.1`

Comment: @Valdimir Thank you. I will change my compiling file. This is my job script file.`#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=demo
#SBATCH --job-name=Quantumtransport
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4
#SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1

module load compiler/2022.0.2
module load mkl/2022.0.2
module load mpi/2021.5.1
mpirun -np 1 ./CODE &` I want to use one node to run the job and divide the computation job with 12 CPUs. Do you think my job script file is written correctly?

Comment: While you do not need `use MPI`, you DO need `use omp_lib`.

Comment: @Valdimir Here is the same error message I obtained after I submitted the job. `===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   RANK 0 PID 21269 RUNNING AT login
=   KILLED BY SIGNAL: 11 (Segmentation fault)
===================================================================================`

Comment: Also, your line is too long. Just forget these scripts and submissions somewhere. Compile your code on your command line by a simple ifort or gfortran command and verify that it runs OK by running it locally. Verify that all variables used have defined values and are properly allocated. Your `km` has no defined value. Then you are allocating some nonsensical amount of memory. There is no point to debug this in this kind of state, really. It is too much of a mess.

Comment: Also, make your code testable without OpenMP. Get rid of those `omp_` functions or use them only when being compiled with OpenMP.

Comment: There are still plenty of unallocated arrays or unitialized variables in this code, making it impossible to test for us.

Comment: What are the definitions for `ZGETRF()` and `ZGETRI()`

Comment: @JAlex ZGETRF() and ZGETRI() are functions in the BLAS library and I use them to compute the inverse matrix.

Comment: @PierU I modified my posted question and added a small complete example, which has the same structure in my code above. Would you please have a look at it and give me some suggestions; particularly, the COLLAPSE and REDUCTION clause in the OpenMP for the nested loop? Do you think it is correctly written? Thank you.

Comment: I always recommend programming in a way that makes it possible to compile your code without OpenMP. Unprotected calls to the `omp_get_num_thread` and similar makes it impossible. But you do not even use the value of  `num_thread` in any way. Just remove it. BTW, you can use `!$` to mark a line of code for compilation only for OpenMP. For those `omp_` functions it is highly recommended to use the `omp_lib` module instead of those `integer omp_get_thread_num` external declarations.

Comment: Also, this is completely a side not, but there is no point whatsoever to open a file with ` `STATUS='UNKNOWN'`. It does not harm here, but it makes no sense. Just remove it and nothing changes and all is clearer. Or use `status="replace"` which does actually make sence there.

Comment: I get the exact same result with and without OpenMP for your code. If there is any problem in your main code, this example probably does not reproduce it. Note that your code tries to allocate huge amount of memory and I just tested a smaller example.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for all your suggestions. I will modify my code. Regarding the small example, you could compile and run it successfully on your cluster. Is it right? If so, I think that the problem I encounter may come from the memory issue on my cluster.

Comment: Do not use a cluster for debugging tests, just use a normal computer.  I used my notebook. And use a smaller size problem. Check whether problem exists or not. Then try larger. Only then try a cluster. Use simple compiletion and run commands. The cluster environment obscures everything. Even on the cluster run from the command line (e.g. `qsub -I`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem, and understand what was happening. But retrospectively it could have been obvious by just reading the code of your reproducible example.

The point is that your `t1` is huge. With the dimensions in the example it has 100x100x1x75*177*177 ~ 23.5 Gelements, i.e. 188GB. Maybe you have the memory to afford it, but after that you are asking for a reduction on `t1`: when reducting a variable/array, OpenMP creates private copies to each thread, exactly the same as if you were specifying `private(t1)`. So, if you have 8 threads OpenMP requires an additional 8x188=1504 GB amount of memory: you very likely do not have that amount... And even if you had, there would be a specific issue with ifort: it allocates private arrays on the stack memory, which is limited. gfortran allocates them on the heap memory if needed, so you are only limited by the total amount of RAM in this case. There is an ifort switch to force the allocation on the heap, though...

The good news is that you don't need the reduction on `t1` at all: you are updating it with `t1(i,j,:,:) = ...`, and because you are collapsing the loops on `i` and `j`, the different threads won't write simultaneously to the same locations. Problem solved...

Still, you need the reduction of `t2` and `t3`, but these ones are small enough and this won't be an issue (however you have to initialize them before the parallel region: you cannot assume the content is zero after the allocation, it is actually undefined).

More observations on your code:

- when privatising an allocatable array with the `private` clause (such as `th`), it's better to allocate it inside the parallel region (because it ensures that the private copies are on the heap rather than on the stack). This requires separating the `OMP PARALLEL` and `OMP DO` directives:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL    PRIVATE(i,j,k,l,m,th)  &
!$OMP             SHARED(km,kp,nm,po,ic) &
!$OMP             REDUCTION(+:t1,t2,t3)
allocate( th(na,na) )
!$OMP DO          COLLAPSE(2)&
do
...
end do
!$OMP END DO
deallocate( th )
!$OMP EN PARALLEL
```

- The memory pattern access on `t1` is awful, even for the serial code. You should allocate it that way:

```
ALLOCATE (t1(na,na,km(1)*km(2)*km(3),nm))
```

then in the computations you would access it this way:

```
t1(:,:,j,i) = ...
```

which is much better as `t1(:,:,j,i)` is a contiguous section in memory, thus minimizing the cache misses, and as `j` is the inner loop (keeping the higher rank index as constant as possible within the inner loop is also cache friendly).

- Last but not not least: do you really need such a huge array? By reorganizing the code, maybe (but I don't know if it's possible) you could compute it by parts, so with less memory needed

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation with so many details. I think that I really need to modify my code and avoid occupying such huge memory by 't1' variable.